# Pandas ffill on section of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna, ffill

I am attempting to forward fill a filtered section of a DataFrame but it is not working the way I hoped.

I have df that look like this:

```
    Col Col2    
0   1   NaN 
1   NaN NaN 
2   3   string  
3   NaN string
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    Col Col2    
0   1   NaN 
1   NaN NaN 
2   3   string  
3   3   string
```

This my current code:

```
filter = (df["col2"] == "string")
df.loc[filter, "col"].fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)
```

But my code does not change the df at all. Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use boolean indexing to filter the section of `Col` where `Col2 = 'string'` then forward fill and update the values only in that section

```
m = df['Col2'].eq('string')
df.loc[m, 'Col'] = df.loc[m, 'Col'].ffill()
```

---

```
   Col    Col2
0  1.0     NaN
1  NaN     NaN
2  3.0  string
3  3.0  string
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question but if you want to fill the NAN values or any values you should use the Simple imputer

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

Then you can define an imputer that fills these missing values/NAN with a specific strategy. For example if you want to fill these values with the mean of all the column you can write it as follows:

```
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy= 'mean')
```

Or you can write it like this if you have the NaN as string

```
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy= 'mean')
```

and if you want to fill it with a specific values you can do this:

```
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy= 'constant', fill_value = "YOUR VALUE")
```

Then you can use it like that

```
df[["Col"]]=imputer.fit_transform(df[["Col"]])
```